# Shell Script Invocation error with Xcode 8 iosopendev

Tags: xcode8

I have created a blank project in Xcode 8.0 but compiling it gives error "**Logos Tweak**" project using Xcode 8.0 but it is giving me error

> "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Do I have to include any other scripts/libraries to run/compile?